# htaccess not allowing to save data in Magento Backend

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I want to remove index.php from all admin URLs in Magento. I have written the following code in my .htaccess file.

Magento is installed in a subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.domain\.com$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.domain\.com$
   RewriteRule ^(/)?$ test/ [L]

   RewriteBase /test/


     RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


    RewriteRule .* index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)index.php/admin.*$
    RewriteRule ^index.php/admin(.*) /admin$1 [L,R]
```

By this code I have found success in my requirement, but now I am unable to save data. Please help me if any one has idea about this.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: if you want to remove `index.php` from the urls then you need to do some settings in system->configuration.. I am not sure what exactly though..

Comment: I have done settings in admin, i.e. System --> Configuration --> Web -> Use Web Server Rewrites to "Yes"

Is there any other setting?

Answer (score 0):

If your all settings are correct and you are making the changes on Live server, then you need to wait at least one day as the 
**Live Server takes some time to change the htaccess configuration setting.** ;)